# MLE estimation with no dependent variable in R (likelihood)

Tags: r, estimation, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, function

I was hoping to estimate two parameters of my model that goes like this:

$$Z=\left[(aP_1)^{1-b}+((1-a)P_2)^{1-b}\right]^\frac1{1-b}$$

I have $100$ observations of $P_1$ and $P_2$ in my dataset. Now I do not have observed values for the dependent variable $Z$ but I DO have a pretty good guess as to what the estimates  $a$ and $b$ are. Not having observations for $Z$ is the reason I am not doing any least squares estimations (I'm not bent on max likelihood in case you have other suggestions).

I was trying to use the [likelihood package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/likelihood/likelihood.pdf) in R to no avail. From what I understand, with no dependent variable (observed), I need to specify a distribution. And I am not sure how to do that. All the examples in the article I linked above are based on a dataset where they DO have observed values for the dependent - and so the codes are pretty straightforward even for me.

I was hoping you could give me suggestions or comments on what approach to use in a situation like this. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be asking how to estimate parameters, or improve a previous estimate, given that you have no relevant data.  How do you hope to accomplish that?  Have you omitted some details of your situation?

Comment: @whuber It is kind of a [CES](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/micEconCES/vignettes/CES.pdf) type of thing. I don't know much about this type of estimation - but I think the goal is providing starting values for the parameters and making use of a grid search to find the parameter estimates with the highest log likelihood values. Don't hesitate to tell me if Im way off - I'm trying to figure this out step by step. Thanks for your comment

Comment: You cannot get started with this model and these data.  Something has to give.

Comment: @whuber [this] is another example. On page 13, they show their PCES function which is later used as a variable in a mixed-effect model. If what you are saying is true, that something is missing, how can they possibly get their estimates for this function in the first place since there is no 'observed data' for PCES? This is the closest example I could find. I know I must be overlooking something, though.

Comment: Look at the code--it *explicitly* requires a response value!  (Your $Z$ is their $y$.)

Comment: I get it now. I was seeing the equation above independently when in fact I should probably have something like:
$log(y)= B_0 + [(a*aP_1)^{1-b}+((1-a)*P_2)^{1-b}]^{1/(1-b)}*B_1 + X_2*B_2 +...$ where the function of $P_1$ and $P_2$ mentioned in the post is included in a mixed effects model along other variables. Since I have values for $log(y)$, I guess I could estimate all the parameters including the coefficients for the other covariates. Would that make sense? @whuber